# Word 2013 Multilevel numbering on heading removes heading

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I can not set a multilevel numbering on my headings in Word 2013. Whenever I try to set numbering to my headings - they get corrupted. The style is completely reset, and paragraphs are not used as Headings anymore, that is I do not see them in document structure map anymore.
From attached screenshot you can see my actions. Any ideas what is causing the problem and how to fix it?

[image]

Interesting thing: on my another computer everything works fine, so I literally have to edit my files on another computer then I need numbered headings.

Answer (score 0):

Check "Set left and first indents with tabs and back spaces" option is set under File > Options > Proofing > Auto correct options > Auto format as you type. This should make your numbering format fine as you expected.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: No, this did not help :(

Comment: Does this setting already applied? and still not working?

Comment: Yes, it is applied. I tried turning it off - stil no result.